# Android cannot find symbol setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled

Tags: android

I'm trying to use [this library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1084) as `Pull`. After compiling the application I get this error:

```
Error:(84, 19) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(com.sample.Classes.PullToRefresh.PullRefreshLayout,boolean)
location: class android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat
```

I'm using `Appcompat` in this application and my manifest is:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: Is `PullRefreshLayout` a `ViewGroup`?

Comment: @pushbit yes. i just import that as library

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a bug in support-v4's ViewCompat.

Curiously the support-v4 library cannot handle setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled() statically. Instead, it uses reflection to get its entity: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/android-5.0.2_r3/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#L631

ViewCompat should handle this method as the same way to ViewPager.